# Android button background is covering up button text

Tags: android, xml, button, layout, background

I have a button that looks as I want it. The only issue is that it covers up the text. I know that it covers it and that the text shows behind it, because if I remove the android:background attribute, the text is shown.

My goal is to have the button, with its text on top of the button.

Here is my button:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dp"
    android:layout_margin="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/timecrunchbutton"
    android:text="Test"
    android:textColor="@color/white"/>
```

As well as the timecrunchbutton.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <!-- Top 1dp Shadow -->
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
                    <corners android:radius="7dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <!-- Light bottom color -->
            <item android:top="1dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/darkblue" />
                    <corners android:radius="7dp" />
                    <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#248349"/>
                    <padding
                        android:top="28dp"
                        android:bottom="36dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
    <item>
        <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
            <!-- Bottom 3dp Shadow -->
            <item>
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/darkblue" />
                    <corners android:radius="7dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
            <!-- Light top color -->
            <item android:bottom="3dp">
                <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                    <solid android:color="@color/blue" />
                    <corners android:radius="7dp" />
                    <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#22A863"/>
                    <padding
                        android:top="36dp"
                        android:bottom="28dp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using

android:layout_height="wrap_content"

in your Button definition instead of

android:layout_height="65dp"

Comment: Great this worked! Do you know why? It would be nice to explicitly define a button's height.

Comment: I had it happen to me before so I noticed it in your code. I think it has something to do with the way layouts are expanded when using a fixed size and custom drawable. I usually try not to set the height as fixed but width seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this may sound dumb, but I feel like I have to ask this too: is your @drawable/timecrunchbutton white?Or has a lot of white in it?

Comment: I've included the xml for it so you can see, but it is all blue and dark blue, so it shouldn't affect the text showing up.

Comment: Agreed.I will think about it and come back with a possible solution.

Comment: I check this thread every day @Vlad, waiting for your possible solution...

Comment: I haven't been active at all around here, got no time at all for that but your reply made me laugh a little! You've got the right answer given by Island Wave, therefor I helped with nothing right here, I am sorry.